# Docker Container NPM Dependencies Not Found

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm, docker-compose

I set up a 2-stage build process for my docker containers. The first stage installs git and runs npm install. The 2nd stage copies the node_modules from stage 1 and then copies the source code from my host. Then it runs the dev server. Everything seems to be working correctly except that when the dev server tries to start it throws this error:

> "frontend_1  | This dependency was not found:  
>                                                                           frontend_1  |                        
>                                                                                     frontend_1  | * vue-free-transform in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/editor/Line.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&"

I exec'ed into the container and checked the node_modules folder and sure enough it is in the correct location and vue-free-transform is in there and appears to be intact. The project is a vue cli 3 project and all webpack/bower settings have been left at the vue cli default.

I've tried removing any volumes used, clearing the npm cache, and manually exec'ing into the container and running npm install.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN npm install

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
#    volumes:
#      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
#      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

I would expect the dev server to startup without issue but instead I get the error message up above. If I'm lacking any important details, please let me know!

Comment: In your Dockerfile after you copy over the from the builder should you not run `npm install` again?

Comment: I don't believe so. The purpose of the builder step is to run npm install and then copy the complete node_modules folder over to the final container. The reason I did it this way was to avoid having to install git in the final image (some of my npm packages are repos).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out... As usual it was just a stupid mistake. The repo was being pulled just fine but the module wasn't ever built so there was no dist folder in it.

Gotta make sure to either commit the dist folder with the module or build it after installing with npm.